# DC appliances running on AC system

Tags: ac, dc, ac-dc, dc-ac

How do DC ran appliances work in an AC electrical system? For example, a house runs on AC, but the microwave runs on DC. How exactly is AC converted to DC? Does that DC power then have to invert back again to AC when it leaves the appliances back into the electrical system?

Comment: Welcome! Please look up the term _rectifier_. It’s as old as AC systems are.

Comment: Your cell phone charges on DC, what is between the AC outlet and your phone?

Comment: `invert back again to AC when it leaves the appliances` ... does a light bulb convert light back into AC?

Comment: I once worked on a motor controller that regenerated the braking energy back into the AC line, but your average appliance's power flow is in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

OP's microwave example is somewhat complex:

- It is likely that the fan you hear when the microwave is turned on uses an **AC** motor, directly from your house power.
- The microwave generator gets its electrons from a heated cathode - it is heated with **AC** whose voltage has been transformed down in amplitude. AC or DC can both heat a resistive element equally well. Since house AC is available, this heater uses some.
- The microwave generator *also* needs high-voltage **DC** to accelerate those electrons - you'll find a diode somewhere feeding this generator that does AC-to-DC conversion.
- The clock, keypad, timer, display are electronic semiconductors, needing low-voltage **DC**, so there's at least one smaller diode for these too.

And what the microwave generates is also called **AC** - its AC power output is transferred to the compartment without wires - confined in a short channel like a duct. But the frequency is far higher than the AC in your house - for every cycle of your house AC, a microwave oven's AC is about 49,000,000 times higher. Radio transmitters are similar to microwave generators.

---

You might ask, "why does house AC need to be transformed to microwave AC"? That's getting into physics of how electromagnetic energy affects physical objects.
Your microwave might pull over 1000 watts from house power. Much of that power is delivered to food in the compartment. What doesn't heat food heats components inside the microwave - transformers, motors, electronics and the microwave generator itself.

Comment: The microwave's rotating platter (nearly all of them have those now) also probably runs on an AC motor.